# why did i got 2 different losses for sparse_categorical_crossentropy and categorical_crossentropy?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tf.keras, loss-function

I trained a model for multiclass classification. There were three classes. In the first approach, I trained a model by converting the classes into one-hot vectors and training a model with loss function, categorical crossentropy, I achieved a loss of 0.07 in 1000 epochs. But when I used the same approach, but this time I did not converted the classes into one-hot vectors and used sparse_categorical_crossentropy, as the loss function, this time i achieved a loss of 0.05 in 1000 epochs.. Does this mean that sparse_categorical_crossentropy is better than categorical_crossentropy?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare two loss functions in term of losses since the definition of loss itself changed. you can compare the performance on the same test dataset.

In general use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` when your classes are mutually exclusive (e.g. when each sample belongs exactly to one class) and `categorical_crossentropy` when one sample can have multiple classes or labels are soft probabilities (like [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]).

You got different losses because the representation of the labels changes, actually in keras the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is defined as categorical `crossentropy` with integer targets